# Check if a textarea changes, and if so, write it's value somewhere

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have one textarea `#text-g` and one div `#textg`. I'd like to make a script for when the textarea changes (Someone type in it), the div display the text.

I've made this pretty simple code, but of course it's not working because there's no event.

```
function myFunction() {
var text1 = document.getElementById('text-g').value; 
document.getElementById('textg').value = text1.val;
}
```

Could someone please explain me how these events work ? 
And does my two-codes are enough, with the event, to do what I would like to achieve ?

Comment: `text1` hold the value of `input`, Try `document.getElementById('textg').value = text1;`

Comment: inside html for textarea <textarea id="text-g" onkeyup="myFunction()"></textarea> you could use onkeyup and onchange both

Comment: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) is how to use eventlisteners and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) is a full list of event, i recommend using change, input and paste event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `oninput` event to track `text` input.

You can read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) about `oninput` event.

And one more thing `DIV` element won't have attribute `value` by default so used `innerHTML` to populate `div#textg` with text from `textarea#text-g`

```js
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('textg').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text-g').value;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-g" oninput="myFunction();"></textarea>

<div id="textg"></div>
```

Comment: But OP said it's a `DIV`

Comment: SoReadyToHelp.  Sorry it's a typo :).

Answer (score 2):

To set the text in div we use innerHTML in pure javascript.

So replace this line

```
document.getElementById('textg').value = text1.val;
```

With

```
document.getElementById('textg').innerHTML = text1.val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery:

```
$("#text-g").change(function() {
    $("textg").text($("#text-g").val());
});
```

Pure JavaScript equivalent:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("text-g");
var div = document.getElementById("textg");

textarea.onchange = function() {
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me the same with pure Javascript, i found it more easily to understand. If I understand correctly, there's no need to actually define what kind of change is made ?

Comment: added a pure JS version.

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Javascript:

```
var el = document.getElementById("text-g");
el.oninput = function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Where is defined the `#textg`?

Comment: In your html file you would have to have an element like this `<textarea id="text-g"></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow as below,

1.Put onkeyup() event in textarea

```
<textarea id="abc" onkeyup="myFunction();"></textarea>
```

2. Make Function as below,

   function myFunction()
   {

   ```
   var txtValue = document.getElementById("abc").value;  
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = txtValue;
   ```

   }

3.Define,where you want to display output text,

```
  <div id="output">  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully working example for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/8w555grw/

```
var out = document.querySelector("#output");
var inp = document.querySelector("#input");
var updateOutput = function()
{
    out.innerHTML = inp.value;
};

inp.addEventListener("keyup", updateOutput);
```

This will capture the input to the textarea, and output it to a div.